# javascript regex - match with or without spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have those expressions:

```
var numRows = 12;
```

And this:

```
var numRows=12;
```

I wnat to replace the '12' to '10' in both of them using regex.

I tried this:

```
var(\s.*)numRows(\s.*);
```

But the second doesn't match.

Comment: How do you express your expressions in JavaScript?

Comment: You mean you those two statements in a javascript file, which you want to edit? What is more relevant for tagging is the tool that you are using for applying the regex.

Comment: It's just a simple. I might as well just write expressions with or without spaces. It does not matter the syntax is in javascript

Comment: \s.* means a space followed by any number of characters, not any number of spaces.

Comment: So, How I test any number of spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding both basic `.` and `*` operators. `.` matches *any* character, thus it matches not the space (because `\s` already does that) but the next character instead. The `*` makes it match as much "any" next characters.

You probably need

```
(var numRows\s*=\s*\d*)\d;
```

I adjusted your grouping (they were useless); now you can replace with `\10;` to replace the final digit with `0`.